# CSS Image flexi width

Tags: css

So I have this banner at the top of my webpage. It looks fine when viewing from my 23" monitor. But when I view it with my 15" square monitor, the banner gets cropped off the right side because its too long.

How do I use CSS to make the width of the banner adjust according to the user's screen size?

Comment: Where's the current css code?

Answer (score 0):

it should not only accord to the users screen size but to the size of the browser window.

try `width: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pixels for setting a fixed width you can use percentage like

width: 100%;